# Jquery fadeOut() is not working in Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a .php file that makes a table filled with items found in a database. 
Here is the while-loop that fills the table:

```
while($request = $list->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  if(!in_array(array($request['artist'], $request['title']), $arrayList)) {
    echo "<tr id='remove-" . $count . "'>";
    echo "<td class='". $count . "'>" . $count . "</td>";
    echo "<td class='artist'>" . $request['artist'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td class='title'>" . $request['title'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . ShowTime($request['time_created']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td><button type='button' class='btn btn-success played'><span class='ion-play' aria-hidden='true'></span></button></td>";
    echo "<td><button type='button' class='btn btn-danger deletesong'><span class='ion-trash-a' aria-hidden='true'></span></button></td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    $count++;

    $arrayList[$request['id']] = [$request['artist'], $request['title']];
  }
}
```

When a person clicks on one of the '.played' buttons, an ajax 'POST' request is sent to set a parameter in the database to 1. This is handled by a different script, which is working correctly, because the parameter is set when I click on the button. This is the jQuery file that handles the click on the button:

```
$('button.played').click(function() {
  var number = $(this).closest( "tr" ).children( ".count" ).html();
  var artist = $(this).closest( "tr" ).children( ".artist" ).html();
  var title = $(this).closest( "tr" ).children( ".title" ).html(); 
  var data = "artist=" + artist + "&title=" + title;
  var trid = "remove-" + number;
  var $parent_tr = $('#'+trid);

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/assets/scripts/php/played_request.php",
    data: data,
    cache: false,

    success: function() {
      $parent_tr.fadeOut( 1000, function() {
        $(this).remove();
      });
    }
  });
});
```

The problem is that even though the AJAX is handled successfully (The success block is called), the `fadeOut` function is not responding, because nothing is fading out. I can't find the problem and this function works in the console.

```
jQuery(parent_tr).fadeOut( 1000, function() {
  $(this).remove();
});
```

Can someone please explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: At least start by using jQuery all the way: `var $parent_tr = $("#"+trid);` and  `$parent_tr.fadeOut( 1000, function() {` later.

Comment: MB `jQuery(parent_tr).fadeOut...` change to this `jQuery('#'+parent_tr).fadeOut...`

Comment: Ok, I've changed my code, but it still doesn't work

Comment: If you put the following in the success handler, what do you get: `console.log($parent_tr.length)`

Comment: I've done that and it logs: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code like:

```
var $parent_tr = $(this).closest( "tr" );
```

As I don't see any element with class like `count` in your HTML.

Comment: Of course! I've given every first td a class, but that is a number instead of the word 'count'. I didn't even notice that. Your solution works. Wow Thank you!

Comment: Welcome @RafS...`:)`!

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities:

1. missing count class from `tr`
2. second change `.html()` to `.text()`

Please try to change `.html()` to `.text()` and try again :-

```
    $('button.played').click(function() {
      var number = $(this).closest( "tr" ).children( ".count" ).text();
      var artist = $(this).closest( "tr" ).children( ".artist" ).text();
      var title = $(this).closest( "tr" ).children( ".title" ).text(); 
      var data = "artist=" + artist + "&title=" + title;
      var trid = "remove-" + number;
      var $parent_tr = $('#'+trid);

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/assets/scripts/php/played_request.php",
        data: data,
        cache: false,

        success: function() {
          $parent_tr.fadeOut( 1000, function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });
      }
    });
```

Comment: Changing .html() to .text() makes no difference. It was the missing count class from the first td that was causing the problem.

Comment: yes thats my first answer...
Now got resolved error?

Comment: Yes, it has been resolved. Thank you for the fast response.